# RubyMotion custom UITableViewCell with nib

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I need some guidance on how to create a custom table cell for my RubyMotion app by subclassing UITableViewCell. I wonder whether my custom class can load a nib file that was created in InterfaceBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am learning RubyMotion too. You can try following step 5 under "Listing Taks" in [this tutorial](https://github.com/mattgreen/nitron/wiki/Tutorial)

I know it's using xcode, and it feels like it defeats the purpose of using RubyMotion, but maybe you can give it a try.

Also checkout [MotionTable](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/motion-table) and [Motion IB support](https://github.com/yury/ib).